# How many transactions per second can Ethereum currently handle? What changes will allow the network to be able to handle more?

Tags: transactions, consensus, casper, scalability, devp2p

I've been searching for a more precise answer to this question, but I've seen a lot of conflicting information stating that Ethereum can currently handle anywhere from 12-45 transactions per second. What is the correct current number?

Then, also, according to [this article](https://www.coindesk.com/information/will-ethereum-scale/):

> In creator Vitalik Buterin's words, the long-term goal is for the platform to be able to process transactions at "Visa-scale transaction levels" or beyond.

"Visa-scale" is referenced as being 45,000 transactions per second.

- So what has to happen at the technical level in order for this goal to be realized?
- More miners?
- More nodes?
- More efficient core code?

Or will a completely new evolution of Ethereum be necessary to reach that level of transaction capacity?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I did the math to show the aprox tx/s:

- The block gas limit is 7,999,992
- Transaction costs 21,000 gas (let's assume nothing else is attached)
- That's ~380 transactions per block
- With a block time of around 15.03 seconds. As https://ethstats.net/ shows.

**This gives us aproximately: 25.346 tx/s.**

At the end of your question, you have mentioned some possible ways to bring this number up.

- The more miners on the network, the more network difficulty, because difficulty calculation algorithms are always trying to make the next block's time be around 15s.
- More nodes will increase the block time even more because more delay between them will appear and then, more time will be needed for them to sync with each other.

> There exists an inversely proportional relationship between the **consensus volume** and the **tx/s rate**. The more time the nodes need to accomplish the sync and achieve consensus, the less tx/s you will have.

To improve all of the features you mention, there are now a few ways on which Ethereum is entering:

- **Sharding (Borns, while you realize that the whole blockchain can't process more transactions than a single node, can):** "Solution" -> We split the state and history up into K = O(n / c) partitions that we call “shards”. For example, a sharding scheme on Ethereum might put all addresses starting with 0x00 into one shard, all addresses starting with 0x01 into another shard, etc. In the simplest form of sharding, each shard also has its own transaction history, and the effect of transactions in some shard k are limited to the state of shard k. One simple example would be a multi-asset blockchain, where there are K shards and each shard stores the balances and processes the transactions associated with one particular asset. In more advanced forms of sharding, some form of cross-shard communication capability, where transactions on one shard can trigger events on other shards, is also included.

**Ethereum Fundation is donating lots of $ in order to incentivate the research on sharding and plasma.**

[Here I leave some really good github's info about sharding.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#on-sharding-blockchains)

Another important improvement is the next:

- **CasperFFG (As said before, PoW consensus algorithm is not scalable, because of that, new Proof of Concepts of consensus algorithms are being researched. Now Ethereum plans to move to [PoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-stake) by implementing CasperFFG to start the transaction period on which 1/100 tx's will be done by PoS. Essentially it's a mixed PoW, PoS algorithm which it's purpose is to arrive one day to a PoS full implementation.)** Solution -> By using PoS consensus algorithms, you eliminate the mining concept (as doing non-profitable calculations to find a hash in a certain range). Then, the block time can decrease till **arriving at even 5 - 7s (Said by Vitalik Buterin).**

[Here I leave the CasperFFG paper's link.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09437)

There are more ideas to improve the speed of the network without losing it's main objective: consensus. But I posted the most important ones.

Hope it helps!

Comment: 7,999,992 isn't "pi million". 3141592 is, which is what the block gas limit used to be :-)

Comment: Propose the edit, I'll accept it!! :)

Comment: I appreciate the incredibly thought out response. I and the community will benefit a lot from this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point on reducing the block time. (Perhaps I'm reading it in the wrong way.) If you reduce the block time to below 15s, the uncle rate will increase, which is bad. The difficulty adjustment algorithms are set so that this block time is maintained - it's not related to the number of mining nodes.

Comment: Similarly, I don't think increasing the number of nodes would increase block time. The block time will stay the same, as per the difficulty adjustment. If a node doesn't receive a propagated message in time, or is unable to validate a block (either because it was late receiving it, or because its hardware isn't good enough), then it just gets left behind. The rest of the network doesn't care that it is slow (and has no way of knowing).

Comment: PoS will have to use a similar size block to allow propagation and validation to happen at a similar rate to PoW. If that's the case, then even if the block time reaches 5s, then that will mean only a 3x increase in TPS, meaning ~75 TPS, rather than anything near 100.

Comment: That's true, and for one single node there's no problem. But with more than 20000 nodes that now are on Ethereum, the propagation time it's important. You have to make sure that at least a considerable percentage of them, is synchronized with the actual blockchain state. And they may force the network to wait for more in order to make sure that a great percentage of the nodes have agreed on the same blockchain state.

Comment: Reviewing now the part of the more miners, I see that i didn't explained myself correctly, i'll edit It.

And finally, yes, will be approximately 75tx/s if we are optimistic, but with all the money that is now invested on Ethereum, we have to understand that the solutions can't come as fast as we want, there's a lot of testing to do before releasing any new improvement. If anything fails, milions and milions will just dissapear. And if I'm not wrong i haven't said anything about 100 tx/s, why did you say that? Was just for info porpouses?

Comment: The blocktime (~15s) was chosen because it was considered enough time for the blocks to propagate to enough of the network. How would they force the network to wait? How do they know how many nodes have agreed on consensus when they don't know the size of the network?

Comment: Okay, I misread the 1/100 txs part (I thought you'd said it could manage 100s of TPS) - my mistake :-)

Comment: Because the 15s calculation maybe wasn't thought to let the blocks propagate enough on a +20000 nodes network. What I was trying to say is that if the number of nodes dramatically increases, maybe this 15s blocktime isn't enough to achieve an acceptable consensus. An then, we have to wait to let the block propagate more time.

Comment: Okay, so you're talking about a protocol change to increase the block time, rather than something that will automatically happen as a result of more nodes joining the network - thanks for clarifying.